# Opacity on hover doesn't work

Tags: html, css

So, I've tried making an image change opacity when you hover your cursor over it. The problem is that changing opacity doesn't work at all.

Here is the code **CSS**

```
.jarleby {
  z-index: 10001;
  position: fixed;
  left: 43%;
  top: 60%;
  margin-left: -45px;
  margin-top: -56px;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.jarleby:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="jarleby animated fadeInUp">
  <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198345955002" target="_blank"><img src="img/steam.png"></img> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Something else is taking precedence. Use !important or sort your rules out

Comment: please `animation` code

Comment: Your code works. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVvwzG be sure to give us a [mcve] that actually replicates your issue, otherwise all we can do is guess.

Answer (score 2):

Something else might be overruling your `CSS` code. Try adding `!important` to the rule of `opacity: 1;` in the `:hover` section. See example below:

```
.jarleby:hover {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.jarleby {
    z-index: 10001;
    position: fixed;
    left: 43%;
    top: 60%;
    margin-left: -45px;
    margin-top: -56px;
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
    opacity: 0.5 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  }
    
.jarleby:hover {
  opacity: 1.0 !important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

```html
<div class="jarleby animated fadeInUp">
  <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198345955002" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The code snippet runs as intended in Chrome v49.x for OS X 10.7

Comment: It's weird that it works when I run code snippet but doesn't work in my code. I also tried adding !important; but with no result.

Comment: Found out what was overruling it, it was the animate.css

Comment: Nice, please mark my answer, if it had helped you. Thanks